# iPhone objective-c wifi spots list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, list, wifi

I've got a question about iPhone developing. Is there a example code or tutorial for getting a list or maybe an array with wifi spots that where find in the current environment?

Answer (score 1):

Check http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/

It used to be done with private APIs, but I have seen a couple apps make it to the store that do this.